# Responsive screen problems

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, screen

Hello so i have tested my new site and it seems like that site with other resolution does not work so good.

Here is first picture (1920x1080)

[image]

And second screen (1360x768x)

[image]

I have also added some Media Queries, but still wont work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) { }
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) { }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) { }
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { }

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
.checkbacksoon p span { font-size: 150px; line-height: 160px; }.error {font-size: 14px;}.search {width: 220px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.checkbacksoon p span { font-size: 150px; line-height: 160px; }.error {font-size: 14px;}.search {width: 220px;}
```

Comment: Without knowing how your html and the whole stylesheet looks like it's hard to tell whats going on.

Comment: Here is [CSS](http://pastebin.com/ddRHVGVa) Code

Comment: can you post your html/css related to your issue or provide a working example?

Comment: Here is [main page code html](http://pastebin.com/iMP2mArp) and here is [CSS](http://pastebin.com/ddRHVGVa) code, or check live [here](http://csgoearth.com/new/)

Comment: thanks. what is the issue? what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Check my screenshots. But i need responsive design for all screens, and  Media Queries did not work.

Comment: you gave fixed width to your elements. You should use percentage widths in order to make them responsive and avoid them to overlap. My advice is to wrap into containers all close elements so that you can easly position the containers instead of all divs.

Comment: The media queries are all empty, you have to set the desired styles inside each media query.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your object that those numbers are on is absolutely positioned...

Try making that big box container

```
position:relative
```

That should at least keep it inside of that.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle, or post some actual code to look at then? I can make a more educated guess that way

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be look into something called "Bootstrap CSS" in order to make your website compatible on all screen resolutions and screen sizes.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Apologies for my answer being extremely vague, just trying to help :)

Hope this helps,

Sohail.